# Detecting Layer Enable/Disable Within Control

Tags: javascript, leaflet

**Requirement:**

I need to be able to detect when a user manually clicks a layer on/off within a Leaflet's map controls.

**Problem:**

I've found the "overlayadd" and "overlayremove" events and have tried to attach my logic to those events, but they seem to also fire during direct "addLayer" and "removeLayer" calls that I have elsewhere in code. This is too general. I only care about when the user initiates the action.

I could attach listeners directly to the control checkbox elements and dig into the DOM to find the corresponding layer name but that's relying on their HTML structure a lot more than I'd like to, since they could change that on a whim.

Are there any events lurking more specific to L.control actions or a way hidden in the overlayadd/overlayremove event parameters to detect what triggered the action? ... or just some other way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `L.Control.Layers` clickhandler fires it sets it's own "private" `_handlingClick` property to true:

```
var marker = new L.Marker([0, 0]);

var control = new L.Control.Layers(null, {
    'Marker': marker
}).addTo(map);

map.on('overlayadd overlayremove', function (e) {
    if (control._handlingClick) {
        // Executes only on input toggle, not on
        // map.addLayer(marker) or map.removeLayer(marker)
    }
});
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! I know this is a pretty low level technical thing but I wish the docs mentioned it. The way they explain the overlayadd/overlayremove events make it sound very much like they fire exclusively from the control interactions.